# ggplot fill in colors for barchart

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, colors, geom-bar

For my project, we created a for loop/if else to assign a color for each of the five NYC boroughs using RColorBrewer.  Here was my code for the for loop for reference. school.safety is my dataset.

```
color_vec<-  vector(mode="character",nrow(school.safety))

table(school.safety$Borough)

borough <- unique(school.safety$Borough)
k <- length(borough)
bor_colors <- brewer.pal(k, "Set1")

for ( i in seq_len(nrow(school.safety))){
  borough <- school.safety[, "Borough"]
   if(borough[i] == "K"){
    color_vec[i] <- bor_colors[1]
 } else if (borough[i] == "M") {
    color_vec[i] <- bor_colors[2]
 } else if (borough[i]== "Q") {
    color_vec[i] <- bor_colors[3]
  } else if (borough [i]== "R") {
    color_vec[i] <- bor_colors[4]
  } else if (borough[i] == "X") {
    color_vec[i] <- bor_colors[5]
    } else {
    color_vec[i] <- bor_colors[6]
  }}
```

We are now using ggplot to create a barchart for the frequency of a particular incident by borough using the colors we assigned. Here is my code for the ggplot:

```
ggplot(school.safety, aes(school.safety$`Scanning Type`, fill=school.safety$Borough)) + 
geom_bar(mapping = aes( color=color_vec, position="dodge", stat="identity")) + 
scale_fill_manual(values=c("Brooklyn"="#377EB8" ,"Manhattan"="#4DAF4A","Queens"="#984EA3","Staten Island"="#E41A1C", "Bronx"="#FF7F00")) +
xlab("Scanning Type")+
 ylab("Count")
```

Here is what our barchart looks like now:
[image]

How can we fill in the bins with the assigned borough colors from the forloop and create a one legend for colors/boroughs. Additionally, if anyone knows how to not stack the barchart and create five seperate bins for each borough per scanning type.

Thanks so much

Comment: First, I would make sure to take the `$` out of the code. They can cause some issues with `ggplot2`.

Comment: Second, I think you want `fill` and not `color` for the `geom_bar`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @AndS. I removed the $ from the ggplot code and changed the 'color' to 'fill' for the geom_bar. However, the colors for the bars are still not filled in.

Comment: Move `fill=` inside  `geom_bar(aes(fill=Borough))`

Comment: @M.Viking Hi! thanks for helping. here is my code `ggplot(school.safety, aes(`Scanning Type`)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=Borough, position="dodge", stat="identity")) + scale_fill_manual(values=c("Brooklyn"="#377EB8" ,"Manhattan"="#4DAF4A","Queens"="#984EA3","Staten Island"="#E41A1C", "Bronx"="#FF7F00")) +xlab("Scanning Type")+ ylab("Count")` but the bars are still not filled in.

Comment: Does this work `ggplot(iris, aes(Species)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=Species)) + scale_fill_manual(values=c("setosa"="#377EB8" ,"versicolor"="#4DAF4A","virginica"="#984EA3"))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color vec is not needed, we do the mapping with a named vector in `scale_fill_manual`.

```
boroughs = unique(school.safety$Borough)
bor_colors = brewer.pal(length(boroughs), "Set1")
names(bor_colors) = boroughs
## now bor_colors is a named vector where the names are boroughs
## and the values are the colors


ggplot(school.safety, aes(x = `Scanning Type`, fill = Borough)) + 
    ## all the aesthetics at the top is usually nice  
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = borough_colors) +
    ## give our named vector to the values
  labs(x = "Scanning Type", y = "Count", fill = "Borough")
    ## labels all together is nice
```

You should use `stat = "identity"` in `geom_bar` when you already have a computed y value and are mapping a y aesthetic. You don't have `y =` in your aesthetic, so I'm pretty sure you **don't** want `stat = "identity"` (though that's just a guess since you haven't shared any sample data).

If your data frame `borough` column has values K, M, Q, R, X instead of the real borough names, before running the above code I would create a new `borough_name` column with the names you want. One way to do that would be making a lookup table and joining:

```
borough_lookup = data.frame(
  borough = c("K", "M", "Q", "R", "X"),
  borough_name = c("Brooklyn", "Manhattan", "Queens", "Staten Island", "Bronx")
)

school.safety = merge(school.safety, borough_lookup)
```

If needed, run this code to create the `borough_name` column and then use `borough_name` instead of `borough` in all of the preceding code. (Creating the `bor_colors` and the plotting code.)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much--it works. it makes a lot more sense to make the borough column beforehand with the actual names!